# Jupyter fails to load notebook "Mismatched anonymous define() module"

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I tried to play with D3.js inside jupyter, I couldn't make it work, among the errors I got I had `cannot find name d3` probably because I was failing to link `D3` properly. Finally, after trying everything I could find on the net such as:

```
HTML('<script src="./d3.min.js"></script>')
```

and

```
%%javascript
require.config({
    paths: {
        d3: './d3.min.js'
    }
});
```

and

```
%%HTML
<script src="./d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

...

I managed to make it work! However I was not able to reproduce the exploit! Worse, in my attempts to make it work again I managed to break my notebook, now each time I am reloading the page I get the following message:

```
Notebook failed to load
The error was:
Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (t){"use strict";function n(t){return function(n,e){return ms(t(n),e)}}function e(t,n,e){var r=Math.abs(n-t)/Math.max(0,e),i=Math.pow(10,Math.floor(Math.log(r)/Math.LN10)),o=r/i;return o>=Rs?i*=10:o>=Us?i*=5:o>=Ds&&(i*=2),n<t?-i:i}function r(t){return t.length}function i(){}function o(t,n){var e=new i;if(t instanceof i)t.each(function(t,n){e.set(n,t)});else if(Array.isArray(t)){var r,o=-1,u=t ...
```

What is happening ? It doesn't even wait for me to run any cell to crash? Is it possible that when I imported the `D3` library using HTML I've injected some import and break some dependencies ? How can I fix this ?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: No :/ just dropped the idea of mixing javascript and python